# Is the usage of "after the break" before the start of a commercial and in an article related?

Tags: etymology, phrases, nouns

The phrase "after the break" is sometimes used before a commercial. It can also used in an article. e.g. "watch the video after the break".

Are these two usages related to each other, apart from having the same three words in the same order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea that is being communicated is the same — an interruption in continuity. The context, however, slightly changes the usage of the term. See [the OED entry on 'break' (noun)](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/22913):

*Break* as used on television is definition 8k, and most often used in the context of a commercial/advertisement interruption.

*Break* as used in articles is definition 8c; it is used these days in the context of an in-text advertisement that the reader must scroll past to read the rest of the article, but it can also denote any other kind of break in continuity of the article — not just a 'commercial' interruption.

Comment: I've also seen it used in lead paragraphs (which is often listed on the front page as well) in reference to the rest of the article, which may or may not be right there, if you're actually reading the article, or just scanning the front page.